# Questioned marked as a duplicate (5 times) and original is answered but duplicate is not tagged as "answered"

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

Looking at this question [align column with text and numbers](https://superuser.com/questions/904400/align-column-with-text-and-numbers) it is marked marked as a duplicate.

The original question has been answered.  My thought is the derivative question could re-display the accepted answer or at least be tagged as "answered".  Logically if the answer is not satisfactory, the second question should not be a duplicate.

Any post marked as a duplicate where the prototype question has an accepted  answer, should also be marked as answered by having its answer count repeat the number of accepted answers on the prototype.

Comment: OK, I'm new here.  Can you explain exactly what you mean by *tagged as "answered"* ?

Comment: "Tagged" is not the best term so I will edit. Basically, there is a counter for answers against questions. My proposal would mean that if a question has been categorised as a duplicate then it should share the counter from the original question.

Answer (score 2):

#### Logically if the answer is not satisfactory, the second question should not be a duplicate.

In that case the OP should edit the second (possibly not duplicate) question and explain **exactly** why the duplicate question (and answers) does not work for them.

They should then try to get it reopened.

Please read [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://superuser.com/help/duplicates) and [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://superuser.com/help/reopen-questions) from the help centre.

Comment: I was thinking more that the backend of Stack Overflow should take the duplicate question out of the list of unanswered questions if and only if the conditions I mentioned are met.

Comment: @tjejojyj If your making a feature suggestion please be specific about which conditions

Comment: @tjejojyj You should make that clear in the question and also use `[tag:feature-request]`

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  I've edited the original post along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

There are conditions which are enforced on questions which are used as targets for duplicates. Such questions must have at least one answer which is upvoted or accepted. This feature (which is somewhat controversial by itself) prevents questions from being closed as duplicates if there is no satisfactory answer to it.

As a result, any question closed as a duplicate is expected to have a satisfactory answer, so if you're looking for a question to answer, you may safely skip closed dupes. After all, that's the purpose of closing.

Concerning the proposal to display the number of answers of dupe targets on dupes, I don't think it's a good idea. It will add complexity and confusion, while the benefit is not clear to me. Again, if the question is closed as a duplicate, it already has an answer and no new answers are needed or accepted. Why would anyone care how many answers it already has?